Will Lightning Web Components get my managed package prefix?
I am wondering if lwc gets a managed package prefix. If the prefix is "ABC", will the component look like ABC__myComponent.js, etc. in VS Code or on an org or will it stay on the default name? I want to know this so that after deploying the package to App Exchange I will not have something like ABC__ABC_myComponent.js

The namespace prefix only applies outside your own package. In other words, internally, you'd write c-a-b-c_my-component or c/a-b-c_my-component, but your subscribers would have to write abc-a-b-c_my-component or abc/a-b-c_my-component. In general, you shouldn't prefix your component names; that's what the namespace is for. Also, I know your question is more hypothetical, but be aware that component names can't start with a capital letter. All the extra hyphens here represent the fact that capital letters and underscores make the name more complicated, so you should avoid excessive strings of capital letters.

Huge thanks for your response! I'll keep those capital letters in mind.
